# differential geometry using Robinson's infinitesimals?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, nonstandard-analysis

Is there a detailed treatment of differential geometry using Robinson's infinitesimals?

Comment: Since you specified Robinson, you might not be interested in the other type of infinitesimals (nilpotent). But Models for Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis by Moerdijk and Reyes treats a number of topics in differential geometry (using both invertible and nilpotent infinitesimals, but mainly the latter). 

Comment: Differential geometry using the infinitesimals Todd mentions is known as synthetic differential geometry: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/synthetic+differential+geometry. There are a couple of online textbooks by Anders Kock listed there.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not aware of much. But two works worth noting are:

K.G. Schlesinger. Generalized Manifolds. Chapman & Hall/CRC, 1997.

I.O. Hamad. Generalized curvature and torsion in nonstandard analysis.
PhD thesis, Salahaddin University - Erbil, 2007.

Answer (score 6):

Somewhat belatedly we developed foundations for differential geometry using infinitesimal displacements [here](http://www.logicandanalysis.org/index.php/jla/article/view/237/106):

Nowik, T.; Katz, M. "Differential geometry via infinitesimal displacements." *Journal of Logic and Analysis* 7:5 (2015), 1-44.